# Как перезапустить существующее React приложение?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

После работы над приложением, приостановил его с помощью CTRL + C (в терминале VS Code), теперь не понимаю, как запустить это же приложение?

Comment: А как вы его запустили в первый раз?

Comment: И ctrl-c это не «приостановка», а в 99.99% случаев просто прерывание выполнения программы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в `package.json` написана команда для вашего приложения, скорее всего `npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

`cd .\Имя папки` (например my-app)
`npm start`